# 2-norm of a matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Given that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ with eigenvector $x$ I need to show

$(1)$ $\|Ax\|_2^2=\lambda\|x\|_2^2$

(2) $\|A\|_2\le \|A^TA\|^{1\over 2}$

I knew $\|Ax\|_2=\sum_i\sum_j a_{ij}x_i$

Comment: And what have you tried? Have you written out the explicit meaning of both sides of inequality 1, for example? Have you applied the fact that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue to try to compare these?

Comment: What you say that "know" is wrong, as the example $A = [1]$, $x = [-1]$ shows.

Comment: I see, then I must admit that I dont know the definition of this 2-norm of matrix

Comment: please explain if you know ..

Comment: $\|Ax\|$ is the 2-norm of a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point is proven as follows.

From the SVD of $A = UDV^T$ we can see that eigenvalues of $A^TA = VD^2V^T$ are just squared ones from $A$. At the same time the columns of $V$ are the eigenvectors of $A^TA$. So, exploiting orthogonality of eigenvectors

$$\|Ax\|_2^2 = \|UDVx\|_2^2 = \|D\left(Vx\right)\|_2^2 = \|De_{\lambda}\|x\|\|_2^2 =  \|\sqrt{\lambda}\|x\|\|_2^2= \lambda\|x\|^2$$

The proof is based on the property of the second matrix norm

$${\displaystyle \|A\|_{2}={\sqrt {\lambda _{\max }(A^{^{T}}A)}}}$$.
$${\displaystyle \|A^{^{T}}A\|_{2}={\sqrt {\lambda _{\max }(A^{^{T}}AA^{^{T}}A)}}}.$$

The same reasoning from the first point says that the eigenvalues of $A^{^{T}}AA^{^{T}}A$ are just the ones of $A^{^{T}}A$ being squared.
So
$${\displaystyle \|A\|_{2}={\sqrt {\lambda _{\max }(A^{^{T}}A)}}}$$
$${\displaystyle \|A^{^{T}}A\|_{2}={\sqrt {\lambda _{\max }(A^{^{T}}AA^{^{T}}A)}}} = {\sqrt {\lambda _{\max }^2(A^{^{T}}A)}}
=
\vert\lambda _{\max }(A^{^{T}}A)\vert
=
\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)=\max(\lambda_{\min}^2(A),\lambda_{\max}^2(A))
\ge \|A\|_{2}^2
$$

**Edit**

The inequality becomes after the notion that $\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)=\max(\lambda_{\min}^2(A),\lambda_{\max}^2(A))$, because eigenvalues of $A$ could be negative.

Comment: Here's a simpler answer for the first one: $\|Ax\|^2 = \| \lambda x \|^2 = \lambda^2 \sum x_i^2 = \lambda^2 \|x\|$, so taking square roots, $\|Ax\| = |\lambda| \|x\|$. (Note that the first claim is actually false, by the example I gave in my second comment on the questions, and that your proof implicitly assumes all evalues are nonnegative.)